# SurfaceView in widget

Tags: android, android-widget, surfaceview

I am implementing a widget for TV application in which I want to show streaming so I have to place **SurfaceView** in it. As widget has RemoteViews, how can I use SurfaceView to set value of **SurfaceHolder**? I have defined SurfaceView in xml. I have searched on internet but didn't find any help. I want instance of SurfaceView so that I can play with it.

Comment: you cant use a SurfaceView there

Comment: @pskink Any alternative for SurfaceView and can you please show me some valid statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> As widget has RemoteViews, how can I use SurfaceView

That is not possible. `SurfaceView` is not available for use with app widgets, as is covered in [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#CreatingLayout).

> Any alternative for SurfaceView

It is not possible to show a video from an app widget. At best, you can try to write your own home screen implementation that does this.