# Flutter - show android homescreen widget in the app

Tags: android, android-layout, flutter, flutter-layout

Is it possible somehow to display Android homescreen widget as a Flutter widget?

I've read about [PlatformView](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-platformview-how-to-create-flutter-widgets-from-native-views-366e378115b6) widget that can embed any Android view inside Flutter app. How is it possible to do the same with homescreen widgets?

Comment: Homescreen widget you mean Launcher widget?

Comment: @AawazGyawali Exactly

Comment: Displaying homescreen widgets from other apps will likely require writing lots of native Android code. Check this: [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/host), [tutorial](http://coderender.blogspot.com/2012/01/hosting-android-widgets-my.html)

Comment: @Pavel Sure, I know. I just saw a lot of Flutter packages that embed native views, like this one: https://github.com/DevFatani/Web_Vuw

Comment: And was just wondering, how it's possible to do a similar thing with homescreen widgets

Answer (score 1):

> **I found a github project which is only for android in flutter but**
>   **initially has  much to solve the problem** 
>    **This** [flutter_home_screen_widget_example](https://github.com/hemanthrajv/flutter_home_screen_widget_example)
>   **github repo**

Also found a similar github [issue26134](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/26134) requesting for the same

Got two more related stackoverflow questions

[questions/44120149/android-lock-screen-widget-in-flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44120149/android-lock-screen-widget-in-flutter)

[questions/47870740/flutter-is-it-somehow-possible-to-create-app-widgets-android-and-today-extens#47887388](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47870740/flutter-is-it-somehow-possible-to-create-app-widgets-android-and-today-extens#47887388)

Comment: This github project, as far as I understand, is intended to show Flutter widgets on homescreen, not homescreen widgets in Flutter app

Answer (score 0):

There is no official support from flutter but you can take a look at this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Svk7xmscKk) explaining how to create a home widget using flutter unfortunately the speak he didn't post the code. It looks like the only solution to add the app widget android code in the generated code which means you should know android development in kotlin/java.

Comment: example code added after 5 months https://github.com/slightfoot/android-note-widget