# Creating clock background using flutter

Tags: flutter

Guys i am creating a clock background app, a background and in the center of it a text showing the hour, you need to open the app the see the clock background but i want it to be displayed at the lockscreen of the phone always, i don't know how to display the clock at the lock screen of the phone, i searched but i didn't find yet a helpfull answer.

The question is how can i put this clock in the lock screen of the phone, whenever i open the phone will be displayed at first, any idea how to do it with flutter.

Comment: Did you already look at https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications?

Comment: yes you can  develop  home/lock screen widget with flutter but in some of requirement you need to also write code in native platforms too.
check out this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44120149/android-lock-screen-widget-in-flutter